# Add the value of another cell in a complex formula

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I found a complex formula that I am using but I want to edit it so it adds the value from another cell to the output.

See Sheet1 here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VrJEEVtYt1r4jPABpazQ31JVmotYF0LV3aroTHAcuq0/edit?usp=sharing

I need to edit the formula in cell D4 so it appends the result with the corresponding value from column B.

Comment: pls explain in more detail what exactly you want and update your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(C4:C="",,TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT(Data!B5:B&"♠", Data!A2), ,999^99), "♠")))&"-"&B4:B))
```

[image: 0]